# Scheduling algorithm for scheduling life

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

To schedule a set of tasks stored in an SQLite database I am taking into consideration :

- Project which a task belongs to `p`.
- Name of the task `t`.
- Due date for this task `d`.

`p` and `d` are optional. Assuming user will input at least `t` and `d`, how to schedule the tasks using a scheduler like the Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS)? CFS was written for much finer granularity (nanoseconds), but it might be possible and maybe more efficient if I can modify it.

A typical entry in the database :

| p | t | d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| _ | Call home | 29/2/2012 |
| Work | Meet boss | 14/3/2012 |
| Work | Ask for raise | 18/3/2012 |
| _ | Book tickets | 10/3/2012 |
| Work | Quit | 14/4/2012 |
| Personal | Get botox injections | 10/3/2012 |
| Personal | Get breast implants | 10/10/2012 |
| _ | Dad bday | 7/10/2012 |

I would like to run this algorithm and receive a schedule for the rest of a day that maximizes throughput. I would like to pass arguments that return a set of tasks depending on my current situation (at work I want to ask it to only return tasks that can be completed at work).

`d` alone is not sufficient to schedule tasks using the CFS. What other parameters I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

the cfs is for scheduling slices of tasks on a cpu.  you are a human and cannot multi-task like a cpu can.  you are much better doing one task to completion.

the tools typically used to solve scheduling tasks for humans are related to [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming).  they allow you to do things like optimise for certain variables (productivity, in your case, which i guess is related to tasks having different priorities) under various constraints (like there being only so many hours in a day, and being unable to do two things at the same time).

it turns out that, in general, this is a hard class of problems and there's no single, really good solution (although many are based around guided search in one form or another).  you need to tweak approaches, try different algorithms, etc.  because of this, various packages have been developed that provide fairly abstract interfaces which let you describe the problem in formal(ish) terms and then try to solve it in various ways.

having said all that, for any one particular case (like yours) it's probably going to be more productive to simply write a direct solution (rather than learn one of these complex packages).  but i don't see using the cfs being part of any reasonable solution.

not sure if that's what you were looking for, or helpful - sorry.  if i were in your position i guess i would try using [choco](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/) because it's the one constraint package i've got some experience with.  but you are not me and i doubt that's a good solution for you - you might be best just searching around based on the info here and then asking another question once you have a better idea of what is possible?